# How to add a resource to target from inside of maven plugin?

Tags: java, maven

So i was making a maven plugin, which main goal would be to generate extra resource inside of the final jar file, but i couldnt find how to actually put the file inside of the jar.

The closest i got was saving the file in the output directory, which doesnt really help my case, and most of the google search results gave me either documentation on how to use "Apache maven resource plugin" or "how to create maven plugins", neither of them having the information i seek =\

**Update 1**:
Tried saving the file to the `target/classes`, but the resulting file is empty (no idea why) and isnt copied to the final jar either way

```java
File dir = new File(project.getBuild().getDirectory(),"classes");
if(dir.exists()){
    File result = new File(dir,"AzimDP.json");
    try {
        getLog().info(gson.toJson(toSave));
        gson.toJson(toSave, new FileWriter(result));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        getLog().warn(e);
    }
}else{
    getLog().warn("Unable to save file since target/classes doesnt exist");
}
```

**Update 2 and working solution**:
turns out i forgot to flush and close the FileWriter, and thus the file was empty. After i fixed that, everything works:

```java
File dir = new File(project.getBuild().getDirectory(),"classes");
if(!dir.exists()) {
    dir.mkdirs();
}
File result = new File(dir,"AzimDP.json");
try {
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(result);
    gson.toJson(toSave, writer);
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    getLog().warn(e);
}
```

Comment: By default, maven-jar-plugin pick up anything from `target/classes`, so just drop your generated stuff there.

Comment: @GyroGearless, does the LifecyclePhase matter for that?

Comment: You should take a look here: https://github.com/mojohaus/build-helper-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/codehaus/mojo/buildhelper/AddResourceMojo.java

Comment: @GyroGearless so i tried what you suggested ([code](https://pastebin.com/TUYPNJhT)), but the generated file is empty (even though the logger on the line above shows that the actual json isnt empty) and even the empty file isnt included in the final jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the working solution based off @GyroGearless comment:

```java
Gson gson = new Gson();
File dir = new File(project.getBuild().getDirectory(), "classes");
if(!dir.exists()) {
    dir.mkdirs();
}
File result = new File(dir, "AzimDP.json");
try {
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(result);
    gson.toJson(toSave, writer);
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    getLog().warn(e);
}
```

where `project` is `MavenProject` and `toSave` is `JsonArray`.
Used in Maven 3 at LifecyclePhase "generate resources"